# iPhone Emulator which works in VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ios-simulator, jquery-mobile

I am planning to use jquery Mobile to create a mobile web app for the iPhone. Is there an iPhone emulator that Visual Studio 2010 can launch and display the app when I start the app in VS?

Comment: Check out [this blog entry](http://www.stemkoski.com/simple-iphone-emulator-for-windows/).

Answer (score 2):

Read Here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SimulatingAnIPhoneOrIPadBrowserForASPNETMobileWebDevelopmentWithWebMatrix2OrVisualStudio2012.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are several of them, but I am not sure how close they come to the original.

Some links to try:

http://www.genuitec.com/mobile/

http://www.puresimstudios.com/ibbdemo/

There's more, just google for "windows iphone simulator"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simulator as well:
http://www.electricplum.com/simulator.aspx?utm_source=nomad&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=Nomad%2BDocumentation